# Spring Data Version Compatibility VS Elasticsearch version Compatibility

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have my Spring version as 3.0.5 and ElasticSearch version as 5.6.10.
Now, I want to migrate Elasticsearch version to 6.3. So, will my Spring be compatible with ElasticSearch 6.3 version.

Thank you

Comment: can't try it at the moment myself, but you can just start a local elastic 6.3 in docker and test your application against that. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/docker.html)

Answer (score 0):

Concerning this README file on git project of [spring-data-elasticsearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch), you can use Elasticsearch 6.5.0 with Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.x.

I haven't tried it yet, but you can give it a try!

Comment: Thanks for the help.

But my requirement is I can't upgrade my Spring version. It would be 3.0.5 only. And I need to upgrade ElasticSearch version to 6.0. So will this be compatible?

Comment: as the link I have posted above says, it will not be compatible. spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0.x is compatible with elasticsearch 5.5.